# mouseDown, mouseup position in javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm coding a small game in JavaScript, and am currently trying to change the direction of the snake using `mousedown`, dragging, and `mouseup`, using the following logic:

- x0 and y0, the position of mousedown
- x1 and y1, the position of mouseup

```js
delta_x = x1 - x0
delta_y = y1 - y0

if (abs(delta_x) > abs(delta_y)) {
  if (delta_x > 0) {
    // gesture to the right
  } else {
    // gesture to the left
  }
} else if (delta_y > 0) {
  // to the down
} else {
  // … etc
}
```

Comment: Did you check your console? http://prntscr.com/qre6mq

Comment: Thanks! it's corrected now

Comment: I suggest not using `alert`, but rather `console.log` to print debug information.

Comment: Is this the whole code? Then I believe I have the answer.

Comment: I just found with the functions mouseUp(e) and mouseDown(e). I get the same values of (x0,y0) and (x1,x2) even after press down and drag the mouse before release it  'function mouseDown(e) {
  x0 = e.clientX;
  y0 = e.clientY;
  alert("Down" + x1 + "," + y1)
}

//Position when mouse up
function mouseUp(e) {
  x1 = e.clientX;
  y1 = e.clientY;
  alert("Up" + x0 + "," + y0)
}